# Lookup pop-up window in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lookup, popup

I have a Visualforce page with a lookup field. When I press lookup button to search, a lookup window pops-up, but it is in classic salesforce page.
[image]
[image]

How can I have a pop-up lookup window in Lightning, when I use a Visualforce page?

Comment: When the page is in VisualForce page, why would a lookup be in Lightning?

Comment: I use lightningStylesheets="true" to look like Lightning and I would like to have the same look at the pop-up window also.

Comment: `lightningStylesheets="true"` only puts lightning css(look/feel) to your VF page, it does not change the domain of the page from VisualForce to Lightning. As the lookup is being opened from Visualforce domain, I believe this wont be possbile.

Comment: I have the [same issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/356748/why-does-a-lookup-field-on-a-standard-page-layout-invoke-a-window-with-classic-s) on a standard layout. Sure wish I could figure this out.