# Why does a lookup field on a standard page layout invoke a window with Classic style?

Tags: lightning, lookup

My company completed a Lightning conversion a few months back, so the entire org is Lightning, but for lookup fields (even new ones) the popup window is styled as Classic:

[image]

[image]

This is not a Visualforce override or other custom page. It's a standard object layout with a typical lookup field. Why is this window coming up as a Classic popup and not as shown under the *Better for Users* section on this [Salesforce blog post](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2017/pro-tip-master-lookup-search-lightning-experience)?

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't, if you're actually in Lightning. Are you sure it's not a page override or something? I just checked, and I'm definitely seeing the new lookup behavior, as expected.

Comment: you're certain that's not a VF page displaying the lookup field or anything? There's no placeholder text either which standard lookups show (ex. search accounts). It can be pretty deceiving (see this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/329629/lookup-pop-up-window-in-lightning)'s screenshot which looks/behaves like yours).

Comment: I am. At least I believe I am. I edited the lookup field out of the standard layout to test that. I saw that very question earlier and decided my issue must be different.

Comment: To which kind of object is the NAICS Code field referring?

Comment: It's a custom object with a handful of custom fields.

Comment: @isherwood Does this custom object have any Visualforce pages associated with custom actions/buttons/links? (even though they should not be used by Lightning right now?) E.g. we have a Visualforce page that overrides the standard Tab button for Accounts. This has caused us problems even though Lightning should not have any reference to it.

Comment: @SanderdeJong, I'm not sure how your question is different from the two above, but this new object does not have any Visualforce page overrides associated with it. We do have many for standard and other custom objects, though, even though we're in Lightning.

Comment: I assume you might have a case created? In terms of Classic, is the ability to switch still there, hidden based on profile, or completely off (`Setup --> Lightning Experience Transition Assistant --> Optimize Phase --> Go To Steps --> Turn off Salesforce Classic for your Org`.

Comment: A _support_ case? No. Turn Off Salesforce Classic is disabled. However, enabling it doesn't change behavior here.

Comment: It may. I've seen strange behaviour of VF Components in LEX (rendered as a full page instead of just component), when the only thing that we identified as different for affected users from non-affected was that they switched back and forth between classic and LEX a lot and used "log in as" heavily. Never truly pinned the cause, but blamed cache and stuff anyway..