# Why does the Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic tab in Object Manager still show in a Lightning org?

Tags: lightning-experience, search-layout, object-manager

My company has completed conversion to Lighting and disabled Classic for all users. This tab still shows in the Object Manager. I haven't found a way to remove or disable these layouts. What's the process for that?

This question relates to my recent [post about lookup layouts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/356748/why-does-a-lookup-field-on-a-standard-page-layout-invoke-a-window-with-classic-s). I'm not sure if the existence of this tab and the layouts on it are what's causing lookups to appear like Classic.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As confusing as the name is, the *Search layouts for Salesforce Classic* tab is used for updating the `List View Layout` which applies to **both** Lightning Experience & Salesforce Classic. As of now, this tab will continue to display to provide that functionality.

This is mentioned in [Customize Search Layouts for Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customizing_search_layouts.htm&type=5) under *Other Layout Options*

> In Lightning Experience, you can select Search Layouts for Salesforce
> Classic. This option lets you easily access layouts for Salesforce
> Classic without switching out of Lightning Experience. Layouts
> include: Lookup Dialogs, Lookup Phone Dialogs (for Salesforce CRM Call
> Center), Search Filter Fields, and Tab. **This page also includes the
> List View layout, which unlike the other layouts on this page, applies
> to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic**. Use the List View
> layout to add and remove the action buttons that users see on all the
> list views for a given object. For example, if you remove the New
> button from the account list view, that button is no longer shown on
> any account list view.

When you click on `Edit` for the `List View layout`, you're presented with a screen that has a section for *List View Actions in Lightning Experience*.

[image]

---

In terms of more background, Winter '20 brought a Lightning-only feature of [Profile-Specific Search Results Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.einstein_search_profile_specific_layouts.htm&type=5&release=222&language=en_US) which created the `Search Layouts` tab you see now in Lightning Experience. This forced the other tab, previously named `Search Layouts`, to be renamed to `Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic` (even though list view layouts still affect LEX).

I took a screenshot from the following [video](https://youtu.be/PjiSTxBWcrk?t=48) (Summer '18) that shows the `Search Layout` tab used to display what is currently in `Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic` in LEX before that profile-specific search layout tab existed.

[image]